# How to remove all the 'ORG' entities collected from Spacy

Tags: python, list, nlp, spacy

I'm working on an `NLP` project and using `Spacy`. Now, I have identified different entities using `NER` of Spacy, and I want to remove the ORG (those identified as Organisations) from the original input string.

```
doc = "I'm here with the three of Nikkei Asia's stalwart editors, three Brits in Tokyo. First off, we have Michael Peel, who is executive editor, a journalist from our affiliate, The Financial Times  . He is now in Tokyo but has previously reported from the likes of Brussels, Bangkok, Abu Dhabi  and Lagos. Welcome, Michael.MICHAEL PEEL, EXECUTIVE EDITOR: Welcome Waj. Thank you very much.KHAN: All right. And we have Stephen Foley, our business editor who, like Michael, is on secondment from the FT, where he was deputy U.S. News Editor. Prior to the FT, he was a reporter at The Independent and like Michael, he's a fresh-off-the-boat arrival in Tokyo and has left some pretty big shoes to fill in the New York bureau, where we miss him. Welcome, Stephen.STEPHEN FOLEY, BUSINESS EDITOR: Thanks for having me, Waj.KHAN: Alright, and last but certainly not least, my brother in arms when it comes to cricket commentary across the high seas is Andy Sharp, or deputy editor who joined Nikkei Asia nearly four years ago, after a long stint at Bloomberg  in Tokyo and other esteemed Japanese publications. Welcome, Andy.ANDREW SHARP"

text = NER(doc)
org_stopwords = [ent.text for ent in text.ents if ent.label_ == 'ORG']
```

`output of org_stopwords`

```
['The Financial Times  ', 'Abu Dhabi  and Lagos', 'Bloomberg  ']
```

This is my code now, I've identified and made a list with all those identified as ORG by Spacy, but now I don't know how to remove those from the string. One problem I'm facing to normally split the string and remove the `org_stopwords` is beacause org_stopwords ar `n-grams`. Please help with some coded example how to tackle this issue.

Comment: could you please add the data in the list of `org_stopwords`? just print it and copy it to the question

Comment: sure, I'll do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Named Entities from the spacy object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60365350/remove-named-entities-from-the-spacy-object)

Answer (score 1):

Use regex instead of replace

```
   import re
   org_stopwords =    ['The Financial Times',
                         'Abu Dhabi  ',
                         'U.S. News Editor',
                         'Independent',
                         'ANDREW']

   regex = re.compile('|'.join(org_stopwords))
   new_doc = re.sub(regex, '', doc)
```

Comment: Thanks, man! You're helping me today much much. I've one question though, the object we are getting back from this is a list, can it is possible I get it back as a string object similar to doc?

Comment: also this is returning back a list with same string repeated in each position of its element with the list number == org_stopwords.  How deal with this?

Comment: @Starlord22 I have added updated code , use regex instead of string replace...

Comment: thanks, man! this seems to be working. However, when I applied this for my project, where the string is a podcast article, a weird error came: `unbalanced parenthesis at position 1061`. Any idea how to fix this?